# UIButton Action not working in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes UIVIewController and UITableviewcell. In UITableviewcell, i have a button and the button action should be in UIViewController. How can i pass a class and set delegate in button action.

i tried this code,

//UIVIewController

```
cell.createButton(self)


func buttonClick(object:AnyObject){
  println("Button Clicked")
}
```

//UITableViewCell

```
func createButton(delegate:AnyObject){
//button created.

    button.addTarget(delegate, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}
```

But the above code is not working. 'buttonClick' function is not calling

Comment: How and when do you all call `createButton(delegate:AnyObject)`? Whats passed in as `delegate`?

Comment: i am calling cell.createButton(self) in cellforrowAtIndexPath. i am passing a class in delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, trying to put self in place of "delegated".

otherwise try to take a look at this question:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736151/custom-cell-error-addtarget-button)

I hope to be helped.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's working. But i wonder, is this is the correct way of doing. In objective c, i think we can pass a delegate and set target in UITableview cell class. why it is not possible with swift?

Comment: actually it should work like you wrote the code, I do not know if it's a bug or is written in a different way. However Self works :)