# UIButton not responding used in a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I know this issue is already been asked few times in SO. Despite trying those out, I am still unable to solve my problem.

I am using a UITableView inside a UIViewController. I have a custom UITableViewCell which has couple of buttons in it. However, I am not able to make the Button respond to Click event.

The development environment is iOS 9 and Swift 2

Snippets used :

BranchNearMeTableViewCell.swift contains

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnDetails: UIButton!
```

view controller class

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("branchNearTableCell") as! BranchNearMeTableViewCell

 cell.btnDetails.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnDetails.addTarget(self, action: "showDetails:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

}

func showDetails(sender: UIButton){

        print("Button Pressed:")
    }
```

Additional Info:

TableView and TableCellView has User interaction disabled in Interface builder since don't want the entire cell to be clickable.

UIButton inside TableViewCell has User Interaction enabled.

Being an iOS noob, I may be making a silly mistake which I might have overlooked.

Similar questions that I checked include:

[SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894765/ios-swift-button-action-in-table-view-cell)

[SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558003/button-action-in-custom-uitableviewcell-in-swift-or-objective-c)

[SO3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736151/custom-cell-error-addtarget-button)

I Deeply appreciate any help regarding this question.

Comment: Enable the user interaction and click the cell in your storyboard. There's a setting called "Selection" and set it to "None".

Comment: For which all controls we need to apply? Tableviewcell and button?

Comment: Everything should have the user interaction enabled. Then select the table view cell and disable the **selection** attribute.

Comment: Thanks @AlejandroIván it now recognises click . But throws an exception "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Thanks done and working @AlejandroIván

Comment: User interaction was already enabled for my UIButton. The thing worked for me is 
switching the stackView distribution to "Fill".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `true` on the table view cell as well. I would prevent taps using the `UITableView` `allowsSelection` to `false`

Also remember to remove the target and action in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` since the cells are recycled, the button might already have the target and action, it might add a second.

Comment: Thanks Kyle , can you please suggest where would be the best place to write the target and action other than tableVIew:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Create an IBOutlet from the button is storyboard, just like you would any other button

Answer (score 88):

I faced a similar issue.  I was programmatically adding an `UIButton` to the `UITableViewCell` via `addSubview`. The button would not respond to touch events.  Using Debug View Hierarchy, I finally discovered that any subviews added to the `UITableViewCell` was behind `contentView`, which was blocking user input from reaching the `UIButton`.  The issue was resolved by adding the `UIButton` to `contentView` instead of the `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! always used addSubview positioning stuff inside of my cells, but contentView.addSubview is what worked. +1 for linked tutorial as well

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you soooo much

Comment: This answer should have 100 upvotes more :D

Comment: adding your views to contentView has its own demerits. I'm a noob, found this helpful a week ago, now after reading a lot to fix my bug, had to downvote this answer.

Comment: This must have changed in later versions of iOS. In some old cold bases adding the button to the cell directly always worked. However at some point it stopped working and now I have to add the button the contentView

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for hours

Comment: this is incredible

Comment: been google searching and came to here! upvote for you! fixed!

Answer (score 13):

I found a simple solution:

Inherits UITableViewCell, and override init()

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    //init subviews, eg. self.switch = UISwitch()
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
                
    // add this line magic code 
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                
    //add subviews, e.g. self.addSubView(self.switch)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The documentation for `isUserInteractionEnabled` indicates that "The default value of this property is true", therefore, this shouldn't need to be explicitly set.

Answer (score 4):

For programmatically created views, the only thing to remember is to declare buttons using `lazy var` in `UITableViewCell`. And also add subviews to `contentView` instead of the cell itself For example:

```
class CounterCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var incrementButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(incrementAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(incrementButton)
        // Your constrains here
    }

    @objc func incrementAction() {
    }

}
```

When using programmatically views, there's no need to add `.userInteractionEnabled` flags.

Then to take the action out of the cell, just add a delegate and assign it from the `UITableViewDataSource`.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to do (in ViewDidLoad):

```
mTableView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue today, with a button inside a static UITableview cell, that was not responding to user events.
I realised the 'Content View' of the cell also has a 'User Interaction Enabled' tick box. Make sure you select the 'Content View' inside the UITableview cell in your Document Outline menu, then tick the box for 'User Interaction Enabled' in the Attributes Inspector - see attached photo for reference. 'User Interaction Enabled' also needs to be checked for the cell for this to work.
Hope this helps. [XCcode screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UusVl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you are adding target actions to your buttons outside their setup. So instead of

```
let button: UIButton = {
    //addTarget...
}()
```

you can have a function to set up your buttons after something happens:

```
func setButtonsUp() {
    // myButton.addTarget
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling, here's my solution:

```
sendSubviewToBack(cell.contentView)
```

The thing that there's now an extra UITableViewCellContentView layer which blocks interaction with views behind it.
Related issue: [An extra UITableViewCellContentView overlay appears in a TableView on iOS 14 preventing taps, but works fine on iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932279/an-extra-uitableviewcellcontentview-overlay-appears-in-a-tableview-on-ios-14-pre)

Answer (score 1):

In your UITableview cell, add the subviews in the ContentView like:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) 
{
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(button)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently had the issue of my tableview custom buttons not registering button presses. Peter Liaws answer is correct, the contentView is blocking the cell from registering buttons. However, by adding the subviews to the content view, your layout could become overly complicated, especially if you're using dynamic height based on your cells constraints. I've found that by simply using:

```
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

You're able to interact with the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Ad a first sight nothing seems to be wrong with your code.
So I suggest you to add a background color to the superview of the button, why? because if the button is outside the frame of its superview it will never receive touches.
 
If you see that the button is not inside the background color probably you have an issue positioning the item, check constraints or whatever you are using.
Check also the frame of the button.
You can also do both by inspecting the view at runtime, [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, tried your suggession by adding background color, the button is positioned within the superview color.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what wrong in the code but i can suggest which i personally use and it works for me

In BranchNearMeTableViewCell.swift

```
@IBOutlet var btnDetails: UIButton!
@IBAction func btnDetailsClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    tapButton?(self)
}
var tapButton: (UITableViewCell -> Void)?
```

In Table view controller

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("branchNearTableCell") as! BranchNearMeTableViewCell

 cell.tapButton = {(user) in
             //User will be tablecell here do whatever you want to do here
        }

}
```

So if you click on button in table cell this cell.tapButton will be called you can do whatever you want to do here

Comment: May I know which all properties you have enabled and disabled in Design  like User Interaction and Selection for TableView and TableViewCell

Comment: user interaction is enabled by default for button and if button interaction is enabled it should work irrespective of tableviewproperties

Comment: share gist for xib and view controllers files then only we can debug the issue more

Answer (score 0):

The only things we need to do is in **cellForRowAt** just put:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

in this way, UITableview will bypass the touch of selecting cells and allow buttons inside our cells to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

- set cell and cell content view isUserInteractionEnabled = true
- Add Tapgesture to the button
- Add a closure to handle gesture action

Answer (score 0):

Add target for that button.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(connected(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Set tag of that button since you are using it.

```
button.tag = indexPath.row
```

Achieve this by subclassing UITableViewCell. button on that cell, connect it via outlet.

Make sure `button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

To get the tag in the connected function:

```
@objc func connected(sender: UIButton){
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ALL of tableView's superviews do have isUserInteractionEnabled set to true

Answer (score 0):

User interaction was already enabled for my UIButton. The thing that worked for me is
switching the stackView distribution to "Fill".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, even though I was adding the button to the `contentView`, I made the mistake of forgetting to set an auto layout constraint pinning the UIButton to the bottom of the superview, and therefore the `contentView` size was still the default `UITableViewCell` size. I only discovered this when checking the Debug View Hierarchy which showed the content view's position compared to the UIButton. (I'll note this mistake as one drawback to managing auto-layout constraints programmatically.)

The content view is the selected light blue view, and with only the top portion of the button being "within" that view, this was the only part that was tappable:

[image: Xcode Debug View Hierarchy Content View Cut Off]

Setting an auto layout constraint to pin the button to the bottom of the view resolved this issue:

[image: Xcode Debug View Hierarchy Content View Includes Button]